Click on element in shadow-root Selenium Python
I am trying to interact with a web page with a script in python Selenium.
Now I found a website with shadow-root. As founded on the web, I tried to use:
shadow_host1 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[id ='bt-inner-page']")
shadow_root1 = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', shadow_host1)
elem = shadow_root1.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".bt72 > svg:nth-child(1)")

The elem is the search button (see picture, red box).
The website is "https://www.tg.casino/en/sports"
I cannot found the elem, the goal is to click on it.
Actually I am using Firefox as browser, seems that the access to shadow root is made (i don't have errors) but I am not capable to locate element (tried with XPATH, CSS_SELECTOR, CLASS_SELECTOR)

You don't wait for shadow DOM to be rendered, so you have this issue, when actually you have your element in partially rendered state.
To wait for rendering you should:

wait for shadow host visbility
get it's internal root
wait for you element to be rendered inside shadow DOM

Example:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
timeout = 10
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)

def get_shadow_root(element):
    return driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)

driver.get("https://www.tg.casino/en/sports")
driver.maximize_window()

shadow_host = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[id='bt-inner-page']")))
shadow_container = get_shadow_root(shadow_host)
shadow_container_root = shadow_container.find_element(By.ID, 'bt-root')
elem = WebDriverWait(shadow_container_root, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.bt72')))
elem.click()

